# A potential multi-agent system?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, agent-based-modeling, multi-agent

For an assignment I have to make a multi-agent system (very open ended, but a short project), something like predator/prey or traffic simulation? It will be written in Jason/Agent speak.  I am at a loss for ideas as to what to actually implement (what is feasible?), as it can be anything, the more bizarre the better!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make idea-generating agents.

The other agents rate the ideas, and either try and steal the ideas that they like, or kill the people with good ideas. Embed some moral code into them so that some types of agents won't be compelled to steal but will try and invent new ideas if one of theirs conflicts with another.

At the end, you can see what types of agents succeed, what kind of ideas are generated, and what is better for society (i.e. agents with high moral code or agents who steal ideas and implement fast).

It will be a hilarious way to possibly model life and the most effective combination of moral/immoral agents to create a productive and efficient society.

Comment: Cheers Chris; I reckon I'll give it a go myself if I get bored enough :)

Answer (score 0):

make an ant farm. pretty simple, they can only travel in certain paths, and all you really have to do is avoid bumping into each other.

if you wanted to step it up, you could do traffic flow, i.e. only a certain number of ants are allowed in a path at one time.

Answer (score 0):

I've always thought that something like [RoboCup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCup) soccer was a pretty cool thing to do as a project (although it kind of pales in comparison to silky's 'idea-generating agents' :) ).